# How to use owl carouse mousewheel in react js

Tags: reactjs, slider, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

Maybe someone knows how to fix my bag.

I added a mousewheel function in my code but it's not working I need a mousewheel in react js

my code look:

```
<OwlCarousel
 className="owl-theme"
 items={1}
  mousewheel
>
<div className="item">
 <img src={slider2} alt="asa"/>
</div>
</OwlCarousel>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Are you following the documentation for owl carousel? https://github.com/laurenchen0631/react-owl-carousel

Comment: @azium yes but can't find any solution related to mousewheel